# How to reverse gravity in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d

I'm trying to figure out how script gravity reversal on collision with an object. How can I reverse gravity?

Comment: Are you wanting to invert gravity for that single item that collides or are you wanting to do it for the entire scene?

Comment: trying to reverse gravity for the single item

Comment: since we're here, I am very, very new to scripting. what does Invalid token '-given characters' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

Answer (score 5):

If it's 2D then you can simply use:
`rigidbody2D.gravityScale = -1;`. You tagged the question `2D` so this should be all you need to do. To toggle isntead of simply set you can change it to `rigidbody2D.gravityScale *= -1;`

If it's 3D and you want the entire scene to have gravity reversed you can do: `Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -1.0F, 0);`

If it's 3D and you want only that single object to have its gravity reversed you'll have to manually do something like @SteakOverflow points out in his answer. I believe what you'll have to do is add a constant `rigidbody.AddForce` call in your `FixedUpdateFunction`.

Comment: If that did the trick for you don't forget to upvote/mark as answer. Also, in the future you'll get more help if you can be more descriptive and add more details to your questions such as what you've tried, what worked, what didn't, etc...

Comment: since you're here, well, first of all, I only have 2 points... I cant rate yet. anyways, what does Invalid token '-given characters-' in class, struct, or interface member declaration mean?

Comment: correction, 1 point

Comment: That would be a syntax error. You're probably missing a quote around a string.

Comment: @Carson You can accept the answer now mate

Answer (score 2):

You should try to disable the rigidbody's [useGravity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html) property when the collision happens and use [AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to fake your upwards gravity, pretty much like the example in [AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) documentation.

Comment: but would the player still be able to jump?

Comment: If you invert gravity what does "jump" mean in your game? It's up to you if it will be able to jump.

Comment: the game will be a puzzle platformer, so when gravity is reversed the player will fall towards the "ceiling"... wait... what if... instead of reversing gravity. I load 2 scenes for every level, one is rightside up the other is upside down and the trigger swaps you between the two but maintains your relative position! GENIUS

Comment: That's way more complicated (and resource intensive) than what you need.